# django settings multiple environments

Tags: django, settings

I'm trying to break apart settings.py into multiple environments so I don't have this giant spaghetti code of conditionals that is easy to mix up and hard to work with.
So far been reading:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/
http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2012/03/10/django-settings-environments/

```
I moved settings.py to rtv2/settings/base.py 
Created rtv2/settings/__init__.py
Created rtv2/settings/develop.py and copied relevant config out of base.py
```

runserver works fine, but when I try to launch apache with WSGI, I get nothing but:

ImportError: Could not import settings 'rtv2.settings.develop' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings.develop

It doesn't matter what I put for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings settings.develop rtv.settings.develop... nothing works.

How do I get apache+wsgi working with multiple settings environments?

no idea, totally frustrated. help.

thanks

Comment: Are your site worked fine with apache + mod_wsgi before spliting the settings into different modules?

Comment: You said you tried `rtv.settings.develop`, but the path of the file is `rtv2/settings`. Have you tried `rtv2.settings.develop`?

Comment: I'm glad you found my blog post useful, but do note the "Update" at the top - I have "seen the light" and now recommend getting your config from the environment instead, so this logic lives outside your app...